# This kind of errors in Java Console for an simple Applet

Tags: java, tomcat, applet

I m trying to run an applet and thats the problems that I take in the Java Console

```
  Java Plug-in 1.6.0_02
Verwendung der JRE-Version 1.6.0_02 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
----------------------------------------------------
c:   Konsole löschen
f:   Objekte in Finalisierungswarteschlange finalisieren
g:   Speicherbereinigung
h:   Diese Hilfemeldung anzeigen
l:   ClassLoader-Liste ausgeben
m:   Speicherbelegung anzeigen
o:   Protokollierung auslösen
p:   Proxy-Konfiguration neu laden
q:   Konsole ausblenden
r:   Richtlinien-Konfiguration neu laden
s:   System- und Bereitstellungseigenschaften ausgeben
t:   Threadliste ausgeben
v:   Thread-Stack ausgeben
x:   ClassLoader-Cache löschen
0-5: Trace-Stufe auf <n> setzen
---- ------------------------------------------------
Laden: Klasse g7appletDialog.class nicht gefunden
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: g7appletDialog.class
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.AppletViewer.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Cause d by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed.
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
... 10 more
```

what is the problem? and now I dont know what I have done because I save 10 times directory, there arent any more feedback at the Java concole any more...

Answer (score 1):

`g7appletDialog` is a bit strange:

1. The convention for class names is to use an initial capital letter.
2. The convention is to use packages (directory paths) like `de.javamunich.g7applet.MainDialog`.

Check the case sensitive correctness of class name *and* file name. (BTW it is hard to change only the case of a Windows file name in one step.)
Maybe you forgot the package name in HTML?

Start afresh with a new sample applet to have valid examples of how to use `codebase` and other attributes. It must be something simple.

If you can, extend your question with the HTML code for the applet, and where the .class file resides.

Comment: here I will upload the html code that I have put inside my JSP